# How to Apply Modifier on selected faces like applying material on selected faces?

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode

You read it right. So today I learned that we can apply a material on selected faces in an object using "apply" button. I was believing that I could do the same with modifiers and particles but I couldn't find the apply button or any other thread that related to it. So it would be the first thread talking specifically about this and I hope any other beginners will find this thread useful.

Bear with me on this: I am ignorant beginner and I never read the manuals

Comment: Well, the simply answer is no, not directly. However you can create vertex groups and assign certain vertices to these groups, and in some modifiers you can limit the effect by choosing a vertex group.

Comment: You can also split your object into two separate objects. It all depends on your needs

Answer (score 6):

You can limit the modifier effect to a vertex group, but it won't exist in every modifiers, and also it will affect the adjacent faces. Example with the *Mask* modifier:

[image]

[image]